# Parsing data in arduino?

Tags: serial, serial-data

I just started working with Arduino and in my project I am trying to achieve the COMM between two Arduino using HC-05 in master and slave mode respectively, I configured it all successfully.

Now I want to send three HCSR-04 distance sensors data from master Arduino to slave Arduino via HC-05. I am sending each sensor data separated by " | ". following is the example format., which I got in serial monitor by connecting the master Arduino directly to PC via USB.

168|200|76

167|200|68

166|200|76

168|200|77

Now the problem is I am not able to read and parse this on the slave side. I tried with serail.readbytesuntill but I could not succeed. Please help me out that how I can read it and parse it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does this mean? `not able to read and parse` ...... you either get no data, so there is nothing to parse or you get data, but you are unable to parse it    .............. what does this mean? `I could not succeed` ..... please describe what actually happens

Comment: it would be helpfull if you add the parts of your code ment for sending and reciving the data. Without it is difficult to find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the comments Birender Brar, we need more information to be able to help you.

One way to accomplish your goal would be to:

Use `Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', buffer, length)` on the slave device to "read" the data in to a `char` array. The serial monitor can be set to automatically send a `\n` character for testing purposes, but your code on the master will have to do this. Send the data **168|200|76** with a **\n** appended to the end of the data: **168|200|76\n**

Parse the data. Here is a example sketch that parses the data in to a `integer` array.

```
// Use Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', buffer, length)
// to fill the char array / string.
char str[] = "168|200|76\n";

// Set array size to maximum number of integers you will receive.
uint16_t myArray[3];

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);

  int counter = 0;
  char* pch = strtok(str, "|");

  while(pch != NULL){
    myArray[counter] = atoi(pch);
    pch = strtok(NULL, "|");
    counter += 1;
  }

  // Print out the contents of the integer array.
  for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
    Serial.println(myArray[i]);
  }
}

void loop(){}
```